# Half-width events in Month view?

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar month view, and am adding all-day events to it.  Is it possible to get those events to display as half of the width of the day so that I can have 2 columns of all-day events each day?

My goal is to limit the height of each day as more events are added.  Currently, when I get around 7 events, and each day can get quite tall.

I hope to save that vertical space by listing the events each day in two columns.  Is it possible?

Comment: You can give your events classes with className:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

Comment: you can use `eventLimit` (and associated settings) to stop the days getting too tall: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-popover